# Excel - Google Sheet - Retrieve the next value until next value changed

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

[image]

In cell B2, I want to write the formula that retrieve the next value until next value changed

For ex:
A2 = 1, A3 = 2 --> B2 = 2

However if next value as same as current value then continue find the next value that different

A3 = 2, A4 = 2 -->Skip, continue find A5 = 3 <> A3 = 2 --> B3 = 3

Please help me on this.
Thank you

Comment: What are you using, Sheets or Excel?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Excel 365 you can use this formula:

`=INDEX(FILTER(A3:$A$9,A3:$A$9<>A2),1)`

or

`=@FILTER(A3:$A$9,A3:$A$9<>A2)`

It takes the values below the current row and removes values that are equal to the current row (FILTER). This is to handle the double 2s.

Then the first value is the one you are looking for.

If you have a table - then you can use this formula - it doesn't depend on a fixed end-cell:

```
=LET(rgBase,[value1],
rgNext,FILTER(rgBase,ROW(rgBase)> ROW(),"-"),
@FILTER(rgNext,rgNext<>A4))
```

[image]

Comment: `INDEX()` not required just use **[Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)** and it works the same way `=@FILTER(A3:$A$9,A3:$A$9<>A2)`

Comment: Ahh - thank you for that - too many new options to combine

Comment: Yes, multiple choices =)